# automatic label resizing in Rebol3 Saphir

Tags: autoresize, rebol, rebol3

I tried to improve [the Tip Calculator example](http://learnrebol.com/rebol3_book.html#section-1.2) a bit, so that "Total: " doesn't disappear when you hit enter on the tip field:

```
REBOL [title: "Tip Calculator"]
view [
    f: field "49.99"
    hpanel [
        t: field "20" on-action [
            set-face x rejoin ["Total: " round/to to money! ((to-decimal get-face f) * ((to-decimal get-face t) * .01 + 1)) $.01 ]
        ]
        title "%"
    ]
    x: title "Total: " facets [ auto-size true ]
]
```

However, the `auto-size` doesn't seem to help the fact that `x` stays too skinny after calculation.  This works:

```
x: title "Total: " 150x20
```

...as does this:

```
x: title "Total:                        "
```

...but how can I get it to resize automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As title seems to descend from **text**, which is defined as **auto-size: false**, it would be the most easy solution to replace title with a style defined with **auto-size: true** e.g **info**

```
 x:  info "Total: "
```

Otherwise you would have to redefine your own title style descending from a autosizing style.

Comment: This *does* work.  How come the `facets [ auto-size true ]` I tried originally doesn't, though?

Comment: because title descends from text which is defined as auto-size false.

Comment: I *had* read that in your answer, and I think I understand.  However, what I don't understand is why `facets [ auto-size true ]` does not override `title`'s definition.  I thought that that was the syntax for overriding definitions, based on other example code I had seen.  So, what then?  Is there no way to override `title` at all, or do I have the syntax wrong?  If the latter, what's the correct syntax?  (Hopefully that clarifies my confusion a bit.)

Comment: That's probably a design decision. If you resize text, you would have to change the font size too. I guess that's not so easy. If you look into r3-gui.r3, you will see, that the style **text** has the line **                 ff/auto-size: false** in the on-resize actor. So that overwrites **auto** always. You can comment that line and observe a different behavior.